# Swift switch default + fallthrough: missing return in a function expected to return 'String'

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I have the following code:

```
func messageForError(error: ApiErrorType)->String{
    switch (error){
    case .ApiError(let apiMessage):
        if let newMessage = apiMessage{
            return newMessage
        }
    case .NoInternetError:
        return "Não foi possível estabelecer conexão com o servidor. Você está conectado à internet?"

    case .RequestError:
        fallthrough
    default:
        return "Não se preocupe, já demitimos o estágiario. \nDeseja tentar novamente?"
    }
}
```

But the compiler print the following error:

**missing return in a function expected to return 'String'**

The switch has a **default**, so all case are handled, I am missing something or the Swift compiler is not that smart ?

If I removed the fallthrough the compiler does compile without any error:

```
    func messageForError(error: ApiErrorType)->String{
    switch (error){
    case .ApiError(let apiMessage):
        if let newMessage = apiMessage{
            return newMessage
        }
    case .NoInternetError:
        return "Não foi possível estabelecer conexão com o servidor. Você está conectado à internet?"
    default:
        return "Não se preocupe, já demitimos o estágiario. \nDeseja tentar novamente?"
    }
}
```

Comment: case .RequestError is missing the return

Comment: @LeoDabus the fallthrough, is used to continue the switch statement,  so the default case should be called and return a string

Comment: The whole function is missing a return in case you never enter the switch, though that shouldn't happen here it is still possible.

Comment: .ApiError has no return value if apiMessage is nil, consider to add an else clause?

Comment: @Akaino In most compile this in not required, like if you have a function with if and else, you don't need to put a return statement in all I will edit the function to be clear

Comment: @Fantini Good catch but, It's not the case, apiMessage is not an optional, I edit the test to be clear that without the `.RequestError` everything works

Comment: I can't reproduce these symptoms (I can get lots of other symptoms, but not the ones you describe). Please include the definition of `ApiErrorType` and make sure in a playground that this is exactly the code that you're having trouble with, and that the second version really works (it shouldn't). (As @Fantini notes, apiMessage has to be optional, or this wouldn't compile.)

Comment: If apiMessage isn't optional why are you using `if let`?

Comment: They are right. You can't use an if let when you don't have any optionals to unwrap.

Comment: @Rob Napier. Sorry you are right, this is the case. adding and else fix the problem

Comment: You have already figured it out while I was playing with the scenario.  But here is it anyway:  http://swiftstub.com/899549001

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro: "Good catch but it's not the case". When debugging, everything you know is wrong. As you proved just now. "if let" doesn't compile with a non-optional value. At Fantini: Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear whether you have figured this out or not. The problem is not that you haven't got all bases covered in your switch statement. It is that not all code paths return a value. In the ApiError case, if the test fails, there is no return executed. If you put a `return` after this test, the code will compile.